# Google classroom authentication based on Domains

Tags: google-classroom

Presently i am working on google classroom API to integrate classroom into my .NET product.My problem is when i execute this method it asking authentication for first time but when i execute this code next time it directly log in as previous log in credentials.Even i change the **client_secret.json** of another(2nd) domain  also it directly login as 1st domain authenticated user.My requirement is when i change the client_secret.json file dynamically in code at run time it will directly log in as domain user of this client_secret.json file rather than previous domain user of client_secret.json file.Is this possible?
    If yes How can i achieve this.Please any one help on this.

```
private ClassroomService getservice()
    {
        using (var stream =
          new FileStream(Server.MapPath("client_secret.json"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
               System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials");

            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                Scopes,
                "user",
                   CancellationToken.None,
            new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
        }
        var service = new ClassroomService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
        });
        return service;k
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to implement OAuth in google classroom](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32070888/how-to-implement-oauth-in-google-classroom)

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Eric Koleda.But my requirement is different.I need to switch between two users,admin directly log in as authenticated user based on their client_secret.json file  change in run time.How can i achieve this

Answer (score 1):

The client_secret.json file holds application-specific credentials, not user- or domain-specific credentials. Changing the client_secret.json file is not the correct way to log in/out users. Instead, you'll need to use a `FileDataStore` with a different path.